# Как убрать bootstrap'овский margin?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

После добавления класса "row" объекты попадают в нужную мне строку но приобретают ненужное мне свойство.
[image: Сами отступы]

Comment: Поясните подробнее, что значит `объекты попадают в нужную мне строку`. Хочу понять, зачем тэгу `<header>` понадобился класс `.row`. Какой результат нужен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Бутстрап предполагает](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro), что блок с классом `.row` находится внутри блока с классом `.container` или `.container-fluid`:

   > Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

   Раз уж используете Бутстрап, правильнее будет не перекрывать свойства `.row`, а завернуть код в недостающий контейнер.
2. Не надо присваивать тэгу `<header>` класс `.row`. Они из разных опер. `<header>` про структуру разметки, а `.row` - про строку в сетке Бутстрапа.

Comment: От margin'ов и padding'ов бутстраповских это не избавит, иногда они действительно мешают.

Comment: @Ep1demic В Бутстрапе паддинг контейнера и маржин ряда друг друга компенсируют.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем проблема? В CSS

```
.row{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Или обертываете нужный *row* в блок и...:

```
.wrap .row{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Если вдруг не работает (bootstrap подключается ниже вашего CSS (по каскадной таблице), задавайте *margin* **принудительно**, например:

```
.row{margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important;}
```